# You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to contact_info without a default

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I am using the command `python manage.py makemigrations`

However, I get this error:

> ```
> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to contact_info
> without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to
> populate existing rows). 
> Please select a fix: 
> 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows) 
> 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
> ```

Here is models.py:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')


class contact_number(models.Model):
    contact_numbers = models.CharField(max_length=13)

class contact_address(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=5)

class contact_info(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    contact_numbers = models.ManyToManyField(contact_number)
    addresses = models.ManyToManyField(contact_address)
```

Comment: it's specific but i don't know how to correct this or put values in db.

Comment: Did you have a different field set as the primary key before? I am surprised that the migration is trying to add an id field.

Comment: If there isn't any important data in the database, then it might be easiest to drop the database and recreate it, delete any migrations for your app, then rerun `makemigrations`.

Comment: i cleared the db, then restart syncdb but error still same :(

Comment: Don't use syncdb, it's deprecated. Clear the database, delete any migrations, then recreate them.

Comment: I had this issue when I forgot to clear out the old migration files AND changed from natural primary key to autoid.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This happens when a different field was marked as primary key with `primary_key=True` earlier and you are removing that (in case of which django tries to add an `id` primary key).

That Django is asking for a default value for a primary key seems to be a bug.

To work around this problem, follow these steps:

1. Supply a random default value when prompted during makemigrations.
2. Go to the migration file generated (under `your_app\migrations\` and delete the `default=x,`, x being the random value you supplied in step 1.
3. While you are at the migration file, make sure the order of actions make sense (e.g., remove/alter one primary key before adding another). Save and close.
4. Migrate as usual.

Comment: Yes that is the problem and the solution, it indeed is a bug it seems, the approved solution is not right.

Comment: @mehmet Great! This workaround helped me move forward finally after trying many other things. It seems this is that bug (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22997). But unfortunately, another bug (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24030#comment:9) got exposed after doing the above. I had to delete the db entirely and rerun all the migrations to be able to use the default `id` field as the primary key.

Answer (score 26):

you could set `default="" and also editable=False.

E.g `first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="", editable=False)`.

Adding id field is unnecessary. Django will add it automatically.

Edit: Deleting the last migration files in your migrations folder and retry again. If it doesn't work, repeat the same process, you will know you have deleted the right file when your "makemigrations" command works.

Comment: i didn't added id field. I want to migrate this model in to database but it showing those message which i don't know how to gone through this.

Comment: Have you ran the syncdb command first? run python manage.py makemigrations yourapp after running python manage.py syncdb

Comment: yup, it shows:
No migrations to apply.
Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then rerun 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.

Comment: why don't you clear the db, then restart with syncdb. python manage.py flush

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields to override the id

Comment: The answer by mehmet solves the problem while this just do something else. "Adding id field is unnecessary. Django will add it automatically." well that is the problem, it seems that in Django 1.9 it doesnt. Happened to me as well.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set a default value. For example:

```
field_eg = models.CharField(default="")
```

means:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
```

Answer (score 3):

Check Your Migration Files

```
./manage.py showmigrations <App Name>
```

```
[X] 0001_initial

[X] 0002_auto_20181204_1110
```

Revert Your Migrations Using

```
./manage.py migrate <App Name> <migration file name>
```

Eg: `0001_initial`.

Or use zero (for complete migration revert)

```
./manage.py migrate <App Name> zero
```

Check Your Migrations

```
./manage.py showmigrations <App Name>
```

```
[ ] 0001_initial

[ ] 0002_auto_20181204_1110
```

Now delete all revert migrations and migrate again.

```
./manage.py migrate <App Name>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar problem when doing makemigration. I had primary key with name 'Identity' and other fields in my models to which I applied makemigrations. Later, I changed primary key name to '_id' and I got this error.

> **You are trying to add a non-nullable field '_id' to swapidentity without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).**

Error is bit misleading, but if you change back '_id' to 'Identity' you will not get that error.

How to fix?
Delete migration script generated under migrations package. Or manually change primary key in your generated migration script.

Comment: I had a similar problem. I had a model, with a oneToOne field that was originally marked as a the primary key. I wanted to remove the primary key stuff and give it a default id. But there was a field on the model called "uid" and I was unable to follow @mehmet's procedure until i renamed the "uid" field to something without "id" in it.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, completely deleting the migrations is a lazy and bad idea. I did a snafu similar to @Afiz Momin and was able to dig myself out.

I had the following setup:

1. A base **abstract** model.
2. Override the `id` field after creation (bad idea)
3. All other subclasses triggered Django migrations to try to create the ID field from the parent class.

So I would get the following **every single time** I ran `makemigrations`:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to <tablename> without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

But there was a way out.

In my first attempt I would just seed a fake value in and then delete the created `id` column, but this was obviously unsustainable. But on a whim I did the following:

1. Backup the migrations directory to `migrations.orig`.
2. Run `./manage.py makemigrations` to make all migrations.
3. Inspect the newly-created migrations file `0001-initial`.

Chances are the model it's complaining about (`<tablename>`) is missing vital info. For me, it was missing the `bases` argument:

```
migrations.CreateModel(
    name='<ModelName>',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('some_field', models.IntegerField()),
            # ... other fields ...
        ],
        options={
            'abstract': False,
        },
        bases=(<base_classes>),
    ),
```

4. Now go back to **`migrations.orig`** and search for the the migration **where the model is first created**. The migration line will look similar to the one above.
5. Once you find the line in `migrations.orig`, modify it to match the new migration code.
6. Restore your original migrations. Delete `migrations` and rename `migrations.orig` to `migrations`.
7. Just for good measure, run `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate`. You should get no error messages anymore!
8. If it complains about another model, follow the same procedure described.

Answer (score 1):

you happen to be generating a relationship between tables, what you have to do is add a field `null = True`, in one of the fields of the tables that the error message is referring to **`(class contact_info).`**

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have non-empty database. There must be line which has not been created through Django ORM.

Do the following:
python manage.py shell

```
from <path_to_your_models> import *
print len(list(contact_info.objects.filter(id = None)))
```

This way you find out how many such rows are there. If you want to keep them just make migration script with some value that you give it to it.

Comment: i used shell and try to add the values in it but it shows :
>>> p1 = contact_number(contact_numbers='12345678')
>>> p1.save()
IntegrityError: myapp_contact_number.contact_id_id may not be NULL

How can i romove django default id or access myapp_contact_number.contact_id_id

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you made some changes in your models.py and tried migrating afterwards. Happened to me once. Deleting the entire database didn't help after all. In case the error is arriving after adding a Foreign Key, you cannot provide a default or it might be unsafe to set default as null.

Probably Django still has some of the previous migrations files in your myapp/migrations/ folder. Deleting those files might help.

Answer (score 0):

The database needs something to populate existing rows.
So here you want to define some value for it you can use default=""

```
 contact_info = models.CharField(default="" ,max_length=15)
```