# can't makemigrations in wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm trying to migrate this model, and I get this error message.

> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to secondsection without a default;

I'm using wagtail 2.11.3
and python 3.6

I want to generate the following:

in CMS to add a title for the page

description

and three sections

the first section will have :

1- text

2- image

3- title

the second section will have:

1- a title

2- three blocks with title subtitle and text

the third section will have :

1- title

2-text

3-image

I've seen this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32991965/you-are-trying-to-add-a-non-nullable-field-id-to-contact-info-without-a-defaul), it didn't work

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.core.fields import *
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import *
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import *
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from wagtail.core.models import Orderable


class AboutUs(Page):
    """About us Model"""
    templates = 'aboutus/about_us.html'
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    banner_image = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )
    first_section_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    first_section_text = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    first_section_image = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )

    second_section_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    third_section_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    third_section_Text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    third_section_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel('description'),
                ImageChooserPanel('banner_image')
            ],
            heading='Banner Section'
        ),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('first_section_title'),
            FieldPanel('first_section_text'),
            ImageChooserPanel('first_section_image'),
        ],
            heading='First section'),
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel('second_section_title'),
                InlinePanel("second_section", max_num=3, min_num=1, label='Second Section'),

            ],
            heading='Second Section'
        ),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('third_section_title'),
            FieldPanel('third_section_Text'),
            ImageChooserPanel('third_section_image')
        ],
            heading='Third section')

    ]

    class SecondSection(Orderable):
        """about us second section"""

        second_section_subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=True, default="", editable=True)
        second_section_Text = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True, default="", editable=True)
        page = ParentalKey("aboutus.AboutUs", related_name="second_section")
```

Edit: I deleted the migrations files and after that, I was able to make the migrations but another problem appeared, when trying to save the form I get a message

> table aboutus_aboutus has no column named second_section_title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deleting the database and then making migrations and after that migrate solved the problem